# Getting function does not exist error in vacuumdb

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We have a function that attempts to (recursively) extract all resource references from a JSONB field in the FHIR format (where a reference looks like this:

```
{
  "reference": "ResourceType/12345"
}
```

It appears to work fine, and I'm able to create my index using ordinary methods:

```sql
directory-db=# drop index index_resources_on_resource_references;
DROP INDEX
directory-db=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_references (KEY varchar, value jsonb)
directory-db-#   RETURNS text[]
directory-db-#   AS $$
directory-db$# DECLARE
directory-db$#   results text[];
directory-db$#   i record;
directory-db$# BEGIN
directory-db$#   IF (KEY = 'reference') THEN
directory-db$#     results = ARRAY[value #>> '{}'];
directory-db$#   ELSE
directory-db$#     CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(value) = 'object' THEN
directory-db$#       FOR i IN
directory-db$#       SELECT
directory-db$#         *
directory-db$#       FROM
directory-db$#         jsonb_each(value)
directory-db$#         LOOP
directory-db$#           SELECT
directory-db$#             INTO results array_cat(results, get_all_references (i.key, i.value));
directory-db$#           END LOOP;
directory-db$#     WHEN jsonb_typeof(value) = 'array' THEN
directory-db$#       FOR i IN
directory-db$#       SELECT
directory-db$#         *
directory-db$#       FROM
directory-db$#         jsonb_array_elements(value) AS value LOOP
directory-db$#     SELECT
directory-db$#       INTO results array_cat(results, get_all_references (NULL, i.value));
directory-db$#   END LOOP;
directory-db$#   ELSE
directory-db$#     results = ARRAY[]::text[];
directory-db$#   END CASE;
directory-db$#   END IF;
directory-db$#   RETURN results;
directory-db$# END;
directory-db$# $$
directory-db-# LANGUAGE plpgsql
directory-db-# IMMUTABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION
directory-db=# 
directory-db=# CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_resources_on_resource_references ON resources USING gin ((get_all_references (NULL, data)));
CREATE INDEX
directory-db=#
```

I'm also able to vacuum the index from psql, but I get a warning.

```
directory-db=# vacuum (analyze,verbose) index_resources_on_resource_references;
WARNING:  skipping "index_resources_on_resource_references" --- cannot vacuum non-tables or special system tables
VACUUM
```

However, when I vacuum from the command line tool, I get an error:

```
~/src/directory$ vacuumdb -z
vacuumdb: vacuuming database "directory-db"
vacuumdb: error: vacuuming of table "public.resources" in database "directory-db" failed: ERROR:  function get_all_references(text, jsonb) does not exist
LINE 2:                          array_cat(results, get_all_referenc...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT
                         array_cat(results, get_all_references (i.key::text, to_jsonb(i.value))::text[])
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.get_all_references(text,jsonb) line 16 at SQL statement
~/src/directory$
```

That said, other than vacuuming from the command line, everything seems to work fine.  Do I care about the warning?  The command line tool is convenient.  Anyway to avoid getting errors in this case?  We're still running PG @ 9.6 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, `VACUUM` will use an empty `search_path`, so the recursive function call to `get_all_references` won't find the function.

Qualify the invocations with the schema name:

`array_cat(results, schemaname.get_all_references(...))`

Alternatively, you could

`ALTER FUNCTION get_all_references(varchar, jsonb) SET search_path = schemaname;`

Here, `schemaname` is the schema that contains the function.

That is also necessary for security reasons. It is a bad idea to have that function depend on the current setting of `search_path`.